# Highest modulo of a group of numbers

Tags: c, permutation, modulo

I wrote some code that goes through all permutations of a given number and return the one that has the highest modulo of 8.

What I'm wondering now, is there an algorithm/ruleset by which I could automatically exclude permutations that cannot have a modulo of 8 higher than the current number?

I've been mulling it over and can't figure it out, but I feel certain that there is something that can be done to optimize the number of permutations that are checked.

Modular arithmetic isn't really my strong suit.

Thank you in advance if you have any ideas!

Comment: What is permutation of a number?

Comment: Could you please show what you tried?

Comment: If I understand correctly, for example, you have an array { 2, 3, 4 } and you're trying all possible modulo operations like 2%3, 2%4, 3%2, 3%4, 4%2 and 4%3?

Comment: Do you mean permutations of a given number *of elements*?  But even if that's what you do mean, I've no idea how modulo 8 fits in that picture.

Comment: I guess that you want numbers that can be obtained from permuting the digits of a given number like {123, 12, 213, 231, 312, 321}. Further, I guess that you get "time limit exceeded" an an online competition. `:)` If so: 1000 ≡ 0 (**mod** 8), so if you have long numbers with _n_ digits, it is sufficient to pick all 3-digit combinations, of which there are _n_! / (_n_ − 3)!

Answer (score 1):

There is no faster way.

If the number wasn't a power of two, it would be slow, but the compiler knows how to handle this, because `y = x % 8;` is the same as `y = x & 0x7;`.  So it only needs two operations to do the job: first extract the 3 LSbits, and then compare.

No possible microoptimizations here.